# Can't open database '.mdf' requested by the Login

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, linq-to-sql

I made a windows forms application and connected it to SQL Server 2008 R2 database. I used LINQ to SQL.

Whenever I start it without debugging at VS 2010, it runs successfully.
But when I copy the project to another folder or to another computer it gives me an error.

```
Can't open database '.mdf' requested by the Login. Login failed for user ''.
```

How can i solve this problem ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please write your connectionstring and also where is you database file

Comment: The DB is in the same folder of the .exe file. This is the connection string >> @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=" + Application.StartupPath + @"\clothesShop.mdf;Integrated security = true"

Comment: can you run visual studio under administrator and tell us what happen after that

Answer (score 0):

You use Integrated security and a dynamic path... so when copying to another computer you have to make sure the integrated security works with the database.. why don`t you try it with username/passwort to check out if this works

If you copy the project to another folder you will have to include the database file.. You receive in both ways the same error? Please keep in mind to start with an easy scenario (trusted location - not a network folder - where you have full access)

Does your mdf file have permissions set for Authenticated Users via integrated security? After that enable full control for Authenticated Users (for testing). You'll have to repeat this for the .ldf file too.

Please try to be more specific about your scenario if this doesn`t help